# Getting error while specifying cellRendererFramework component within detailCellRendererParams

Tags: angular, ag-grid

Getting following error while specifying cellRendererFramework component `"cellRendererFramework": CheckboxCellComponent` for `[detailCellRendererParams]="detailCellRendererParams"` in `ng-grid-angular` with `[masterDetail]="true"`

Below framework component is working fine for `gridOptions` but throwing error for `detailGridOptions`

> ag-grid: you are specifying a framework component but you are not using a framework version of ag-grid for : cellRenderer at ComponentResolver.getComponentToUse

```
detailCellRendererParams = {
    detailGridOptions: {
      columnDefs: [
        {
          "field": "isActive",
          "cellRendererFramework": CheckboxCellRenderer
        }
    ]}
};
```

Checkbox Renderer Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ICellRendererAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { ICellRendererParams } from 'ag-grid';

@Component({
  selector: 'checkbox-cell',
  template: `<mat-checkbox [ngModel]="params.value" (change)="onChange($event)"></mat-checkbox>`
}) 
export class CheckboxCellRenderer implements ICellRendererAngularComp {

  private params: ICellRendererParams;

  constructor() { }

  agInit(params: ICellRendererParams): void {
    this.params = params;
  }   

  onChange(event) {
    this.params.data[this.params.colDef.field] = event.checked;
  }

  refresh(params: ICellRendererParams): boolean {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add in your **app.module.ts** the following

```
import { CheckboxCellRenderer } from "path_to_file";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    CheckboxCellRenderer ,
 ],
 imports: [
    AgGridModule.withComponents([CheckboxCellRenderer ]),
  ],
```

withComponents call is necessary to be able to use Angular components as cells / headers

Answer (score 0):

When you receive that error is likely because you are not including the associated version of the framework for ag-grid...

Your package.json you should run something like this (if you use angular and want the latest grid v19)

npm install --save ag-grid-community

npm install --save ag-grid-enterprise

npm install --save ag-grid-angular

(Make sure that these are also the only three dependencies that you have that refer ag-grid)